# Codimension of irreducible closed set in an open set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following proposition about Krull dimension of topological spaces. Let $U$ an open set of noetherian topological space $X$, and $Y\subset X$ irreducible closed set, and let codimension $\operatorname{codim}_X(Y)=\dim(X)-\dim(Y)$. I want to prove that

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{codim}_{U}(Y\cap U)=\operatorname{codim}_X(Y)
\end{align*}

I appreciate help with this.

Comment: This is false as stated - are you sure you've got the full claim in your post? Your question could also use some improvement: what has your progress so far looked like?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the assumption that $X$ is noetherian. Occurs that I was reading some things about dimension and I found this result, but I didn´t understand the proof. In that demonstration they say that there is a bijection between closed irreducible subsets of $U$ and irreducible closed subsets of $X$ such that intersects $U$. On the other hand, noetherianity is not assumed, and codimension $\operatorname{codim}_X(Y)$ is defined as supremum of chains of irreducible closed subsets such that contains $Y$. Neverthless, I think that in noetherian case these notions of codimension coincides.